# Add Rows In a empty dataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am building a MVVM - WPF Application. 
I have few dataGrids where the CRUD operations work fine.

Now, I want a dataGrid always empty at the beginning and where of course I can add rows. So I can fill it but when I click save, nothing is saved.

Why?

## **ViewModel:**

```
public class InvoiceViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Context ctx = new Context();
    public InvoiceViewModel()
    {
        this.Collection = new ObservableCollection<Invoice>();
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Invoice> collection;
    public ObservableCollection<Invoice> Collection
    {
        get
        {
            return collection;
        }
        set
        {
            collection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Collection");
        }
    }
    private Invoice _selected;
    public Invoice Selected
    {
        get
        {
            return _selected;
        }
        set
        {
            _selected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
        }
    }
    private void Get()
    {
        ctx.Invoices.ToList().ForEach(invoice => ctx.Invoices.Local.Add(invoice));;
        Collection = ctx.Invoices.Local;
    }
    private void Save()
    {
        foreach (Invoice item in Collection)
        {
            if (ctx.Entry(item).State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added)
            {
                ctx.Invoices.Add(item);
            }
        }
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
    private void Delete()
    {
        var id = Selected;
        var invoice = (from i in ctx.Invoices
                    where i.idInvoice == id.idInvoice
                    select i).SingleOrDefault();
        Collection.Remove(invoice);
    }

    #region "Command"
    // private ICommand getCommand;
    private ICommand saveCommand;
    private ICommand removeCommand;

    /*public ICommand GetCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return getCommand ?? (getCommand = new RelayCommand(p => this.Get(), p => this.CanGet()));
        }
    }
    private bool CanGet()
    {
        return true;
    }*/
    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return saveCommand ?? (saveCommand = new RelayCommand(p => this.Save(), p => this.CanSave()));
        }
    }
    private bool CanSave()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public ICommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return removeCommand ?? (removeCommand = new RelayCommand(p => this.Delete(), p => this.CanDelete()));
        }
    }
    public bool CanDelete()
    {
        if (Selected != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

## **View:**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:InvoiceViewModel x:Key="invoice" />
    <local:ShopViewModel x:Key="shop" />
    <local:SupplierViewModel x:Key="supplier" />
    <local:ProductViewModel x:Key="product" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ProductDataTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding product}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridInvoice"
          Margin="5"
          Grid.Row="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectionMode="Extended"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dataGridTextColumn"
                            Header="Supplier Invoice Nb"
                            Width="*" />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Ref Supplier"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Products, Source={StaticResource supplier}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="refsup"
                                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding refSupp}"
                                SelectedValuePath="refsup"
                                Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit"
                            Binding="{Binding unit, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity"
                            Binding="{Binding quantity, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Prix/MOQ"
                            Binding="{Binding unitPrice, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Price"
                            Binding="{Binding totalPrice, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            Width="*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button  x:Name="BtnDelete"
             Content="Delete"
             Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             Margin="100,5,5,5"
             Width="85" />
    <Button  x:Name="BtnAdd"
             Content="Save"
             Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             Margin="20,5,5,5"
             Width="85" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: are you getting objects in collection?

Comment: yes I do. And it works.

Comment: so where exactly are you getting the probelm?

Comment: Actually, I don't want to get the items. I want an empty dataGrid where I can add new rows which will be save in the database. But nothing is saved.

Comment: I believe it never goes inside the if condition ((ctx.Entry(item).State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added)
), is it?

Comment: Yes, It did. I checked it.

Comment: It goes ot it didn't ? i couldn't make out from your reply.

Comment: Sorry. It went inside the if condition.

Comment: ok. problem solved !! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this method which actually binds the `Collection` to the cached local of the entity set. Without binding, it's harder to save the added items:

```
private void Get() {
        ctx.Invoices.ToList().ForEach(invoice => ctx.Invoices.Local.Add(invoice));;
        Collection = ctx.Invoices.Local;
}
```

In fact it can be just like this to load all invoices and cache to Local:

```
private void Get() {
   ctx.Invoices.Load();
   Collection = ctx.Invoices.Local;
}
```

However as you said you want an empty data grid at first (just for adding), then you can refactor the `Get` method to accept a bool indicating if the data should be loaded from db first or not:

```
private void Get(bool loadDataFirst) {
   if(loadDataFirst) ctx.Invoices.Load();
   Collection = ctx.Invoices.Local;
}
```

Now by using the `Get` method without loading data first, your `Collection` is still bound well to the `Local` cache (which should be empty). After adding new items to `Collection`, the `Local` will have those items added automatically and the `Save` can just call the `SaveChanges`:

```
private void Save() {
   ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

The `Get` method should be used inside the constructor replacing `this.Collection = new ObservableCollection<Invoice>();` like this:

```
public InvoiceViewModel() {
   Get(false);
}
```

Comment: I don't see a call to this method ! m i missing something?

Comment: @Nikita which method do you mean?

Comment: Get() method which you were talking about.

Comment: @Nikita you can scroll through the OP's code carefully it's a private method right above `Save()` method. It might be used before when the OP loaded all data into the grid, but he now wants an empty list (so he did not use `Get`).

Comment: not the declaration, i meant the call to Get() function. anyways, it is solved !! :)

Comment: On other forum, I have read things about "Wrapper" and harder solution. I was sure it was simple.